# How do I align a two columns table, to make the first column be in the center?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to align a 2 columns table so that the first column is on the center (horizontally) and the second column just stays next to it. I came up with some problems trying to do so. Could someone please tell me how do I do it?

This is more or less my table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
first colum first row
</td>
<th rowspan=2>
second column
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
first column second row
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Diagram:

```
                                 center
                            | first column | second column |
```

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of how you'd like the output table to look?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really picking up what you're puttin' down here.

Comment: Thanks. I just added a diagram in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand but I think your problem can be solved with `<col>` tag.
I let you check: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_col.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you can do it.  A simple way would be to make a three column table, center it, hide the border, and then use CSS to only draw a border around the 2nd and 3rd column.  That way the 'first' column would be in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for displaying tabular data, or is this for laying out things to be in the right place on the screen - e.g. two columns of text like a news paper, or a column of text and a side menu?

Unless you're displaying data, its better to use  to create areas of the page (your columns) and then use css styling such as float:left to position them correctly on the screen.